# clean database when creationg a new couple index

Tags: mysql

I am creating a new unique index of two fields:

```
ALTER TABLE `tools`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `name_url` (`name`, `url`);
```

The problem is that the db has already 500000 tools and other tables refer to it.What's the best strategy to remove the doubles?

Comment: You mean remove duplicates?

Comment: @Barmar yes, sorry I didn't know how to say it. But it's the whole process that I'm interested, not for the single table alone.

Comment: What other process? Do you mean you need to fix all the foreign keys that refer to the rows that will be removed?

Comment: @Barmar yes. I need to know which tools.id get dropped so that I can change the keys on other tables and drop others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update another table that refers to this table, do:

```
UPDATE otherTable AS o
JOIN tools AS t1 on o.tools_id = t1.id
JOIN (SELECT name, url, MIN(id) AS minid
      FROM tools
      GROUP BY name, url) AS t2 
ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.url = t2.url AND t1.id != t2.minid
SET o.tools_id = t2.minid
```

This sets all foreign keys to point to the minimum ID for each `(name, url)` pair. You'll have to do this for every other table that has foreign keys pointing to `tools`.

Then delete all the extra rows:

```
DELETE t1.* FROM tools AS t1
JOIN (SELECT name, url, MIN(id) AS minid
      FROM tools
      GROUP BY name, url) AS t2 
ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.url = t2.url AND t1.id != t2.minid
```

Once you've done all this you can add the unique index.

Comment: thanks. That will solve one part of my problems. I have some foreign keys that have to be deleted, but I suppose I could do it by using the second query for that.